Problemas con vue js 3.0 al leer codigo QA con zxing_reader.wasm
Hola comunidad actualmente estoy presentando un problema con la visualizacion de un codigo QR estoy haciendo uso del componete ensamblado zxing_reader.wasm, estoy usando vue js 3.0
       async function onDetect (codigosdetectados) {
         qrResult.value = detectedCodes.map((code) => code.rawValue);
         emit("archivo", result.value);
         paused.value = true;
         setTimeout(() => {
         paused.value = false;
         }, 500);
         }


el problema es que no lee los codigos pero tampoco manda error
